# Why is the break statement in the code not working (python)

Tags: python, pycharm

this is code to print the lowest positive integer present in a list.
break statement is not working and the loop is running infinitely.

```
  list = []

n=1

print("enter array")
for i in range (5) :
    a=(int(input()))
    list.append(a)

while n<4 :
    for i in range (5) :
        if(list[i]== n):
            n=n+1
            continue
        else:
            print("the number should be" , n)
            break
```

Comment: i think this line         if(list[i]== 'n'): should have been         if(list[i]== n):

Comment: The answer to your question is that the "break" statement refers to the for loop and not to the while loop. The if statement is always False (because list contains integers and you compare it to a string), so the code enters the for loop, breaks it immediately and restart with a new for loop, an so on...

Comment: You should not use variable name "list" because it is reserved to the builtin object list.

Answer (score 3):

the break statement refers to the inner most loop level

the code below is an infinite loop:

```
while True:
    for i in range(10):
        if i == 5:
            break  # breaks the for, start a new iteration of the while loop
```

To break the while loop, you may consider using some kind of flag like this

```
while True:
    broken = False
    for i in xrange(10):
         if i == 5:
             broken = True
             # break the for loop
             break
    if broken:
        # break the while loop
        break
```

the for-else statement may also be helpful here:

```
while True:
    for ...:
         if ...:
             # break the for loop
             break  # refers to the for statement
    else:
        # the breaking condition was never met during the for loop
        continue # refers to the while statement

    # this part only execute if the for loop was broken
    break # refers to the while statement
```